# How to define the positional parameters padded_shapes of function padded_batch() in a text classification tutorial of tensorflow.org?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to tensorflow and now learning the tutorials of tensorflow.org. Here is the website of the tutorial I'm learning: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification

But it doesn't work when I run the code below:

```
BBUFFER_SIZE = 1000

train_batches = (
train_data
.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
.padded_batch(32))

test_batches = (
test_data
.padded_batch(32))
```

It seems the problem is that the required positional parameter *padded_shapes* of `padded_batch()` is not given.
I have learned how to use the function `padded_batch()` and tried several ways like `padded_shapes=[None]` or `padded_shapes=([None], [None])`, but it still doesn't work. Instead, it raises the error below:

`ValueError: The padded shape (None,) is not compatible with the corresponding input component shape ().`

So I don't know how to figure out the problem now. Had anyone learned this tutorial and how do you sovle it? Could someone give me some tips about how to define `padded_shapes`?

Thank you!

Comment: Please try below code and let me know if this solves the problem 

```padded_shapes = ([None],())
train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(32,padded_shapes=padded_shapes)
test_batches = test_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(32,padded_shapes=padded_shapes)```

Comment: @Veeru Yes, it works with `padded_shapes = ([None], ())`. Thank you very much! Could you please tell me why it works with this value?

Comment: Please refer how padded_batch works at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch. If I have answered your question, can you please accept my answer and up vote it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to do that. But I don't have the privilege to vote now because I'm new in this site and have less than 15 reputation. When I vote, the site popup a message below:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below code

```
padded_shapes = ([None],()) 
train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(32,padded_shapes=padded_shapes)
test_batches = test_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(32,padded_shapes=padded_shapes)
```